# multiple package.json files in react nodejs project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, package.json

I am new to react and am trying to create a project that makes use of react, node, and express. Having a lot of issues setting up react correctly by myself, I decided to use create-react-app.

I found a bunch of tutorials online and a lot of them seem to suggest separating the front end and the back end into different directories resulting in two package.jsons.

so the project structure would look something like this:

```
Root
|
------client
|       |
|       -------package.json with front end dependencies
|
package.json with the back end dependencies
```

The client diretory is the one created with "npm init react-app" and also contains the package.json that has the react-scripts. Currently if I use command "npm run build" in the client directory it creates a build without the backend files inside the root folder, and if I use "npm run build" in the root folder it doesn't work because I do not have create-react-app scripts in that package.json.

My main question is how would I make a build of my project if I have two package.jsons and if it is normal/best practice to split up front end and back end like this?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This folder structure is one of the most used structure. You are actually separating front-end and back-end, that would result in scalable architecture.

To build your project from one single command, you need to install a dependency `concurrently`. It will enable multiple commands at once. Then make changes to your root `package.json`.

Below is an example `package.json` :

```
"scripts" : {
     "build-client": "npm run build --prefix <FRONTEND_FOLDER NAME>",
     "build": "<YOUR SERVER BUILD COMMAND>",
     "build-project" : "concurrently \"npm run build\" \"npm run build-client\""
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. With my front end package.json the build command is setup with "react-scripts build" from create-react-app, but my back end package.json does not have a build script setup. Do you know if npm has a default build command(I tried npm build but doesnt work) or how I would be able to create a script similar to create-react-app's build command.

Comment: Can you please post you package.json of your back-end and front-end please? However, the server are not meant to be build, they simply run. A typical command would be `node index.js`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to separate CRA(create-react-app) and backend server(express).
This means you have to run front and back in different port and then make a npm scripts that boths run front and back.

Like this.

ROOT/package.json

```
"client": "cd client && yarn start",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
```